# Objective C - Force AuthenticationChallenge

Tags: ios, objective-c, https

I created an ios App that authenticates to the server with HTTPS, server-certificate and client-certificate authentication. 
All of thi worked when I used the development server to connect to, but now that I want to connect to the testing server I have a problem.
The testing server is behind a netscaler. Now everytime I make a request, the

```
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge
```

delegate is not called because I receive HTTP-Code 200 and the netscaler´s login page instead of an authenticationchallenge.
Is it possible to force this delegate or to send the challenged-credentials directly with the initial request?

**EDIT:**
I also tried it with the way you should do it before iOS 7, with the methods

```
connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace
```

and

```
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge
```

but still the same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can't be solved from the iOS-side because:
The delegates you mentioned are not called when the HTTP response code is 200 because the OS assumes the request was successful.

Your Netscaler is the problem.
Either reconfigure it to forward the request to your app server, or if possible, don't use Netscaler in this instance - circumvent it.